# Cannot figure out how to find the list item after the one that I click

Tags: jquery, list, listitem

I am having trouble displaying the name of the image that comes after the one I click. I've tried various ways to accomplish this, including $(this).parent().next() and
$(event.target).next(). It seems like a simple enough thing to accomplish, but the results always return undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8" />
        <title>Example</title>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery.js"></script>

        <script type = "text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() 
            {   
                /* Output the filename of the clicked picture */
                $('.pic').click(function(e) 
                {
                    var currentImage = $(this).closest('li').find('img').attr('src');
                    $('#showCurrentPicName').html('<h1>You clicked ' + currentImage + '</h1>');
                });

                /*Output the filename of the picture after the one that is clicked. */
                $('.pic').click(function(e)
                {
                    var nextImage = $(this).next('li').find('img').attr('src');
                    $('#showNextPicName').html('<h1>The next image is ' + nextImage + '</h1>');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Pictures</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a class = "pic" href = "#"><img src = "brass.jpg"</a></li>
                <li><a class = "pic" href = "#"><img src = "sunburst.jpg"</a></li>
                <li><a class = "pic" href = "#"><img src = "ice.jpg"</a></li>
                <li><a class = "pic" href = "#"><img src = "horizon.jpg"</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id = "showCurrentPicName"></div>

            <div id = "showNextPicName"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what you expect when click on last image? `$('.pic')` select all `a` tag, so inside click handler, `this` refers to `a` and if you want get `li` simple `$(this).parent()` will be enough. Also for get curent image you not need get `li` because image inside `a`

Comment: your `img` tag looks broken. you sure your HTML is laid out correctly? `img` tag doesn't seem to closing properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.pic')` select all `a` tag, so inside click handler, `this` refers to `a` and if you want get `li` simple `$(this).parent()` will be enough. Also for get current image you not need get `li` because image inside `a`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Output the filename of the clicked picture */
  $('.pic').click(function(e) {
    var currentImage = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    $('#showCurrentPicName').html('<h1>You clicked ' + currentImage + '</h1>');
  });

  /*Output the filename of the picture after the one that is clicked. */
  $('.pic').click(function(e) {
    var nextImage = $(this).parent().next().find('img').attr('src');
    if(nextImage)
      $('#showNextPicName').html('<h1>The next image is ' + nextImage + '</h1>');
    else
      $('#showNextPicName').html('');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>Pictures</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="pic" href="#">
        <img src="brass.jpg"/> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="pic" href="#">
        <img src="sunburst.jpg"/> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="pic" href="#">
        <img src="ice.jpg"/> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="pic" href="#">
        <img src="horizon.jpg"/> </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="showCurrentPicName"></div>

  <div id="showNextPicName"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I figured out my problem and I think it was my jQuery file. I was using 1.11 and tried using 2.1 but it still didn't work. When I tried using the link to jQuery like you had the code worked the way it needed to. I'm not sure why it happened that way, but again, thank you.

Comment: @MichalPatriak do you see any errors in browser console when use your files?

Comment: No, nothing pops up. I am running it with Firebug to look for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the index of the element you click and then get the element with index + 1.
untested code:

```
var index = $(this).parent(0).index();
var next = $(this).parents('ul:first').find('li:nth-child('+(index+1)+')');
```

Comment: Just added it to my code, but I still get an undefined result. My copy of jQuery is also current as of this morning for this file.

Comment: Help me help you. Do you get at least the right value for index?

Comment: I ended up finding out it wasn't the code that was bad, it was the jquery file. Using 1.11 nor 2.1 worked. It only worked when I linked to jquery directly from the website.